# Autoload error: Module 'Mageplaza_Smtp'

Tags: magento2.2, error

Hi I am getting the below error

Autoload error: Module 'Mageplaza_Smtp' from '/home/goodwwdm/public_html/new/app                                                                                                                                    /code/Mageplaza/Smtp' has been already defined in '/home/goodwwdm/public_html/ne                                                                                                                                    w/vendor/mageplaza/module-smtp'.

how to resolve the error. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: As per your error, I think you have installed using composer as well manual into app/code, Remove anyone from app/code or from vendor using **php bin/magento module:uninstall** command

https://github.com/mageplaza/module-core/issues/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saying like magento core vendor directory already have Mageplaza_Smtp installed. So solution is you can delete the whole folder located in app/code directory.

Delete /home/goodwwdm/public_html/new/app/code/Mageplaza/Smtp folder.

Run `php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:d:c && php bin/magento s:s:d -f && php bin/magento c:f`